# rsync server autocompletion not working for files when using double quotes on zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcard, rsync, oh-my-zsh

I've just discovered the <strike>range wildcard</strike> brace expansion {..} from the shell ({05..18} will match 05, 06…, 18).

I use zsh autocompletion (tab) to navigate on the server hierarchy and escape special char correctly.

My example is using a simple file hierarchy on the server :

folder1

➡️folder2[x]

➡️➡️file1

➡️➡️file2

The path `/folder1/folder2[x]/file` will be escaped with the correct amount of `\`.

`noglob rsync server:/folder1/folder2\\\[x\\\]/file1 .`

This is working to get file1 and file2:

`noglob rsync server:/folder1/folder2\\\[x\\\]/file[12] .`

but this is not:

`noglob rsync server:/folder1/folder2\\\[x\\\]/file{1..2} .`

*The source and destination cannot both be remote.*

The problem is with the `..` (I think) so I use double quotes `"` to escape the server part.

`noglob rsync "server:/folder1/folder2\\[x\\]/file{1..2}" .`

(note there is now only 2 `\` before `[` and `]`)

But, when constructing that command with autocompletion, completion is working for folder names but not file names.

`noglob rsync "server:/`

tab

`noglob rsync "server:/folder1/`

tab

`noglob rsync "server:/folder1/folder2\\[x\\]/`

tab

(nothing is added)

The expected result after the last  is

`noglob rsync "server:/folder1/folder2\\[x\\]/file`

EDIT:
I’ve just noticed completion is not working **only** when the last folder needs escaping for it’s name (spaces or [… in it).

EDIT 2:
Completion is working with single quotes (and escaping only needs one `\` with them).

`noglob rsync 'server:/folder1/folder2\[x\]/`

tab

`noglob rsync 'server:/folder1/folder2\[x\]/file`

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this, but: brace expansions are *not* wildcards; they behave in fundamentally different ways, so it's not suprising the same approach you use for wildcards doesn't work for them.

Comment: Don't add `Solved` to your question's title. Please _close_ your question or add an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Just to be sure, is there a way to close a question? I haven't found a way to do it, and searching how to do it, I found an answer saying to answer to my own question and accepting the answer (what I've done) or deleting it if the solution would not be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completion is working with single quotes (and escaping only needs one `\` with them).

`noglob rsync 'server:/folder1/folder2\[x\]/`

tab

`noglob rsync 'server:/folder1/folder2\[x\]/file`